# regex get comma seperated values between two words

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, pcre

I have the following query & PRCE regex from which i want to get table names.

```
 FROM   student s, #prefix#.sometable, subject s, marks s   WHERE  ...

(?<=\sfrom)\s+\K(\w*)(?=\s+where)
```

Desired result `student s` `subject s` `marks s`
I cant figure out how to extract from 1st match.

I'm trying to find & replace in sublime text editor.

Comment: Try this one `\w+\s+[a-zA-Z][,\s*]`

Comment: @bobblebubble thanks for your input. That works with addition of match braces `()` but it selects invalid entry if the prefixed values is the last table name. https://regex101.com/r/mF9bY8/3

Comment: I removed answer because it won't be ever useful for anybody. [This was the last demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM3vY6/1) modify to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. i have got some good understanding from your help. I'll try to tweak that for my needs. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @bobblebubble solution which worked 90%, i added a bit more conditions to match my case. it works but its very aggressive and hangs the editor on large or multiple files. But i can live with what i have got. Hers the solution:

```
(?is)(?:\bFROM\b|\G(?!^))(?:[\s,]|#[^\s,]++)*(\b\K(?:\s*(?!WHERE|LEFT\b)\w+){4,})\b(?=.*?\bWHERE\b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: \s+(\w*\s)*s

```
    pcre *myregexp;
    const char *error;
    int erroroffset;
    myregexp = pcre_compile("\\s+(\\w*\\s)*s", PCRE_CASELESS | PCRE_EXTENDED | PCRE_MULTILINE | PCRE_DUPNAMES | PCRE_UTF8, &error, &erroroffset, NULL);
    if (myregexp) {
        int offsets[2*3]; // (max_capturing_groups+1)*3
        int offsetcount = pcre_exec(myregexp, NULL, subject, strlen(subject), 0, 0, offsets, 2*3);
        if (offsetcount > 0) {
            pcre_get_substring(subject, &offsets, offsetcount, 1, &result);
            // group offset = offsets[1*2];
            // group length = offsets[1*2+1] - offsets[1*2];
        } else {
            result = NULL;
        } 
    } else {
        // Syntax error in the regular expression at erroroffset
        result = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: He wants a regEx for **sublime** !!